# How to modify ShortcutToText function to return different result for numpad keys?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

The [`ShortcutToText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCutToText) function (in Delphi 7) returns the same result for shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> as for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>.

How can I modify this function to return different result for numpad keys ?

Comment: So then take the `ShortcutToText` function and modify its line `$60..$69: Name := Chr(WordRec(ShortCut).Lo - $60 + Ord('0'));` to something like `$60..$69: Name := Chr(WordRec(ShortCut).Lo - $60 + 'Num' + Ord('0'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Virtual key codes for the numpad digit keys are `VK_NUMPAD0 .. VK_NUMPAD9` as documented in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

The ordinal values are `$60 .. $69`. The `VCL.Menus` function `ShortcutToText` doesn't make a distinction between `$30 .. $39` (which are the normal digit keys) and the numpad digit keys.

It should be trivial to write a function that does.

And @TLama already shows you how, change this:

`$60..$69: Name := Chr(WordRec(ShortCut).Lo - $60 + Ord('0'));`

Into this:

`$60..$69: Name := 'Num' + Chr(WordRec(ShortCut).Lo - $60 + Ord('0'));`

Comment: Note that you may need to modify `TextToShortCut`, as the one in 'menus' won't use your modified `ShortCutToText` version unless you modify VCL source.

Comment: That's true, if you want it to work both ways you also have to use a custom `TextToShortcut`.